# Trying to get Netsuite JSON Data into Excel Via Restlet

Tags: excel, netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to use Excel to connect to a netsuite restlet script to pull information and populate a sheet.

I have tried to connect via "web" and entering the url and adding headers. If I try to add the content-type to be application/json, I get an error that "name":"INVALID_RETURN_DATA_FORMAT","message":"Invalid data format. You should return TEXT"

I saw that I can connect to a JSON file via Excel, or to a webservice, but it doesn't seem to return the json object. Is there something I am doing wrong? I have the authorization and content-type headers, and my url is correct for the external url of the webservice. Is there a better way to do this?

The purpose of this file is to essentially pull down records of a certain type into Excel, allow the user to edit, and then push that information back into Netsuite. The restlet is working well, now I just need to get the Excel portion working properly.

Thanks!

Comment: I built something similar in the past, but my implementation only brought data down from NetSuite, never pushed things back. I ended up having to use a combination SUITElet and RESTlet to get the authentication and return type to work properly. I would love to chat more about what you built and possibly collaborate on additional functionality. My contact info is in my profile, shoot me a message sometime.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a `Content-Type` Header in your request.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

NetSuite looks at this not only to identify the request body format, but also the encoding of the Restlet's response. (It's a bit counter-intuitive, because usually an `Accept` header is used to tell the server the response content type expected, especially if you are just sending a `GET` request that doesn't even have a body.. but that's NetSuite..)

For more details see the Help Center topic "[Creating a Content-Type Header](https://system.na2.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4619215993.html)"

Comment: Hmmm, okay, I have done this, but now I just get [Object object][Object object][Object object][Object object][Object object] in my response text. When I try to parse this, i get an error, since it is obviously not json. I know that the restlet returns the proper json because if I run it using postman, I get the right information in the right format.

Comment: I got this error when trying to call Restlet through Postman. Adding "Content-Type" fixed it for me. Thanks!